# How i can show a toast message only one time per click for the current activity

Tags: java, android-studio, toast

How i can show a toast message only one time per click for the current activity i mean when a user click my button at the first time it shows a toast message but when he click again no toast message appear again

Comment: How can people answer your question without seeing the code you used? Think about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `boolean` variable and attach it to an `if statement` and set it to `false`. Once the button is clicked set it to `true`. In the `if` statement add it like this `if(booleanVar==false){YOURTOAST;booleanVar=true}`.
To briefly explain this, the `booleanVar` is your switch, you can turn it `true`(on) or `false`(off)...

Edit:

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Context;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    public static boolean booleanVar = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Button yourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourBtn);
        yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void OnClick(View v){
            if(booleanVar==false){
                Toast yourToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "YOURTEXT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                yourToast.show();
                booleanVar=true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give me example please?

Comment: @ahmedmohamed I already added my example in the post edit, check it out!

Comment: thanks too much i will try it and go back to u again

Comment: it works perfect thanks man

Comment: @ahmedmohamed Welcome man, happy to help! Good luck with that project of yours!